# Error in storing results in list

Tags: r, list

```
    res <- list()     
    for(i in 1:4){    
      for(j in 1:10){     
      res[[i]][j] <- j     
      }    
    }
```

I am unable to store results in the list named "res". When I run this code it shows subscript out of bounds [[i]]

Comment: Not sure whats wrong, but I was able to form the list using your code as-is.

Comment: Try `res <- vector("list", 4)`.

Comment: @Hack-R - You were right. I think I had formed a `list` of 4 accidentally before running the `for` loop. @DHWANI DHOLAKIA - You need to initailze your list `res <- list(0,0,0,0)` should help.

Answer (score 2):

`res` is an empty list, so you can't access elements of it by number (you can with vectors though). Add the elements, and it will work:

```
res <- list(0,0,0,0)

    for(i in 1:4){    
      for(j in 1:10){     
      res[[i]][j] <- j     
      }    
    }
```

Do note that this kind of code can be slow; if you already know how many things will be in each vector, create vectors of the appropriate size:

```
res <- list(numeric(10),numeric(10),numeric(10),numeric(10))
```

Comment: Had a trivial mistake I fixed, but I think this is a better answer than mine. +1 cheers

Comment: @Hack-R           why does this work                                                     temp <- c()    
res <- list()    
for(i in 1:4){    
  for(j in 1:10){    
    temp[j] <- j       
  }    
  res[[i]] <- temp     
}

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
res <- as.list(matrix(ncol=1,nrow=4))     
for(i in 1:4){    
  for(j in 1:10){     
    res[[i]][j] <- j     
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` is good for this

```
library(purrr)
res <- map(1:4, ~map(1:10, ~.x))
```